# php Parse user input

Tags: php, forms, parsing, testing, input

I'm currently trying to use PhP to "parse" user input.
The page is just a form with one input field and the submit button.

The result I want to achieve is to make PhP echo(rand(0,100) if the user types "rand"
But if the user types something of this form : "rand int1-int2" it echos "rand(int1,int2)"

I'm currently using switch, case, break for user input.

Thank you in advance !

```
<form action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="commande" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="envoyer!" />
</form>

<?php if (isset($_POST['commande'])) {

    switch($_POST['commande']){ 
        case "hello":
            echo"<h1> Hello </h1>";
        break;
        case substr($_POST['commande'], 0, 4)=="rand":
            echo(rand(1,100));
        break;
        }

    }
?>
```

Comment: So what progress have you made so far? Is it possible for you to pastebin what you have so far?

Comment: I added the code i have so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

```
<?php
    $input = 'rand 1245';
    list($command, $arguments) = explode(' ', $input);
    $arguments = explode('-', $arguments);
    switch($command) {
        case 'rand':
            print_r($arguments);break;
            $min = 0;
            $max = 100;
            if (count($arguments) == 2) {
                $min = (int)$arguments[0];
                $max = (int)$arguments[1];
            }

            echo rand($min, $max);
            break;

    }
?>
```

[**Live example**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/PB6wFb)

Comment: Oh nice ! I understand how the code works, but how is it possible to combine it with the "switch", "case x", "break" form ? Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: I also forgot to ask something. What happens if the "delimiter" in the explode function doesn't exist ? Thx !

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek I've updated my code to use a `switch` statement. If the delimiter doesn't exist, it will just return the whole string, which is why you want to put checks in place like my `if (count($arguments)...`

Comment: I still have an error for the "random" input but I will figure this out later. Thanks for your help !

Comment: @AwakeZoldiek well if you can't solve it don't hesitate to ask. Maybe show me your code and the problem and I can help.